# Mockito when method call not invoked, Verify return message "Wanted but not invoked,Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock"

Tags: mockito, powermock

I am new to Mockito.
I have a problem.
I am trying to mock a class and call a method of that class with a hashmap which returns the same hashmap modified.
But i see that mocked method is not invoked. If i did verify i got the message as "Wanted but not invoked,Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock"

Here is my code
Class to test

```
public class ClassA{
    private ClassB bb = new ClassB();

    public boolean init() {

        bb= new ClassB();
        bb.init();

        return true;
}

    public void methodToTest(){    
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> hashmap= new LinkedHashMap<>();

        hashmap = bb.method1(hashmap);
    }

    public ClassB getBB() {
       return bb;
    }

    public void setBB(ClassB bb) {
       this.bb= bb;
    }
}
```

My Test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestClassA {       

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest({Utilities.class, Logger.class, LoggerFactory.class})
    public void getData() throws JsonProcessingException, JSONException {


        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> hashmap= new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> newHashmap= new LinkedHashMap<>();

        ClassA class2Test= new ClassA ();
        ClassB mockClassB= Mockito.mock(ClassB.class);



PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassB.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockClassB);
        Mockito.when(mockClassB.method1(hashmap)).thenReturn(newHashmap);
        Mockito.verify(mockClassB).method1(hashmap);

        class2Test.methodToTest();



    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to mock the `bb` object in your method. You will have to use `PowerMockitos` `whenNew` functionality if you want to do that. But the usual recommendation would be that you refactor your class instead (if you can adjust the code). -- The mock you currently create is unrelated to `ClassA`. Also you probably forgot to add a variable name for that object and your example is missing the invokation of the `methodToTest` on it.

Comment: If you want to mock the field, you should use ReflectionUtils.setField() method as the Mockito.when does not work in this case.

Comment: I have edited my code with the things i missed.I also tried using PowerMockito.WhenNew on Class B object but i see that it is getting inside the method of CLass B and not mocking it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed a few things together.

With the refactored version you need to inject the mock for `ClassB` into `ClassA` (no need to use `PowerMockito.whenNew`).

Also note that the `verifiy` call has to be after the test method invocation.

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SampleTest {

    static class ClassB {
        public Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> method1(Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> hashmap) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    static class ClassA {

        private ClassB bb = new ClassB();

        public void methodToTest() {

            Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> hashmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            hashmap = bb.method1(hashmap);
        }
    }

    @Mock
    ClassB bb;

    @InjectMocks
    ClassA class2Test;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> hashmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> newHashmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        Mockito.when(bb.method1(hashmap)).thenReturn(newHashmap);
        class2Test.methodToTest();

        Mockito.verify(bb).method1(hashmap);
    }
}
```

---

For your old code the test would look something like this, but if you can use the version above.

The `@PrepareForTest` has to contain the class where the byte code should be manipulated, in this case `ClassA`.

```java
@Test
@PrepareForTest(ClassA.class)
public void test() throws Exception {

    Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> hashmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> newHashmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    ClassB bb = Mockito.mock(ClassB.class);
    Mockito.when(bb.method1(hashmap)).thenReturn(newHashmap);

    PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassB.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(bb);

    ClassA class2Test = new ClassA();
    class2Test.methodToTest();

    Mockito.verify(bb).method1(hashmap);
}
```